# How to set the browser I have developed as the default browser?

Tags: vb.net, browser, default-browser

I'm working on a Web Browser in VB.NET and I want to set the option of making it the default browser. Any help? Tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Becoming the Default Browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144154%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser) in MSDN's default programs API docs

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in VB6, needs to be converted

```
Const REG_SZ As Long = 1
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
Const KEY_SET_VALUE = &H2
Const KEY_ALL_ACCESS = &H3F
Const REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE = 0
Const HWND_BROADCAST = &HFFFF
Const WM_SETTINGCHANGE = &H1A



Private Declare Function RegCloseKey Lib "advapi32.dll" _
  (ByVal hKey As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegCreateKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
  Alias "RegCreateKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
  ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, _
  ByVal lpClass As String, ByVal dwOptions As Long, _
  ByVal samDesired As Long, ByVal lpSecurityAttributes As Long, _
  phkResult As Long, lpdwDisposition As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegOpenKeyEx Lib "advapi32.dll" _
  Alias "RegOpenKeyExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
  ByVal lpSubKey As String, ByVal ulOptions As Long, _
  ByVal samDesired As Long, phkResult As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RegSetValueExString Lib "advapi32.dll" _
  Alias "RegSetValueExA" (ByVal hKey As Long, _
  ByVal lpValueName As String, ByVal Reserved As Long, _
  ByVal dwType As Long, ByVal lpValue As String, _
  ByVal cbData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" _
  Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
  ByVal wParam As Long, lparam As String) As Long
Public Function SetClient(iClient As Integer, sDisplayName As String, _
  sClientCommandLine As String, sClientResourceDLL As String, _
  iLocalization As Integer, bGlobalClient As Boolean, _
  Optional sCLParameters As String, Optional bMakeDefault As Boolean) As Integer

  ' iClient - 1 for internet browser, 2 for e-mail client
  ' sDisplayName - the name to be displayed on the menu for the client
  ' sClientCommandLine - the path and filename of the e-mail client
  '
  ' The next two parameters are included for localization of the client.
  ' For backwards compatibility with applications that do not support localized
  ' strings, the name of the application in the installed language should be set
  ' as the Default value for the key.
  ' sClientResourceDLL - provides a path to an EXE or DLL containing the
  '   localized strings for the client.
  ' iLocalization - a string resource ID within the DLL whose value is
  '   to be displayed to the user allowing the same registration to
  '   be used for multiple languages.  For each language, provide a
  '   different Resource DLL, and the dynamic loading of the string
  '   from the DLL results in the correct strings being displayed, depending
  '   on the language.
  '
  ' bGlobalClient - sets the value for either all users (True) or the
  '   current user (False)
  ' sCLParameters - additional parameters on the command line to be passed to the
  '   browser or e-mail client.
  ' bMakeDefault - (Optional) set the browser or e-mail application as the default

  Dim iStatus As Integer
  Dim hHandle As Long
  Dim hGRegKey As String
  Dim hLRegKey As String
  Dim sCommand As String
  Dim sKey As String
  Dim sAll As String
  Dim sRoot As String
  Dim hKey As Long
  Dim sLoc As String
  hGRegKey = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  hLRegKey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER


  If iClient = 1 Then
    sRoot = "Software\Clients\StartMenuInternet"
  Else
    sRoot = "Software\Clients\Mail"
  End If

  ' Create and null terminate needed strings
  sCommand = "shell\open\command"
  sKey = sRoot & "\" & sDisplayName
  sAll = sKey & "\" & sCommand
  sLoc = "@" & sClientResourceDLL & "," & iLocalization & Chr$(0)
  sClientLocation = """" & sClientCommandLine & """" & _
    IIf(sCLParameters <> "", " ", "") & Trim(sCLParameters) & Chr$(0)
  sDisplayName = sDisplayName & Chr$(0)

  ' Create a registry key for the new client
  iStatus = RegCreateKeyEx(hGRegKey, sKey, 0&, vbNullString, _
    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0&, hNewKey, lRetVal)
  iStatus = RegCreateKeyEx(hGRegKey, sAll, 0&, vbNullString, _
    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0&, hNewKey, lRetVal)
  If iStatus = ERROR_NONE Then
    iStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(hGRegKey, sAll, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, hKey)
    iStatus = RegSetValueExString(hKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, sClientLocation, _
      Len(sClientLocation))
    iStatus = RegCloseKey(hKey)
    iStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(hGRegKey, sKey, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, hKey)
    iStatus = RegSetValueExString(hKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, sDisplayName, _
      Len(sDisplayName))
    ' Add the localization string
    iStatus = RegSetValueExString(hKey, "LocalizedString", 0&, REG_SZ, _
        sLoc, Len(sLoc))
    iStatus = RegCloseKey(hKey)
  Else
    SetClient = iStatus
    Exit Function
  End If

  '  Sets browser as local or global default if specified
  If bMakeDefault Then
    If bGlobalClient Then
      iStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(hGRegKey, sRoot, 0, KEY_SET_VALUE, hKey)
      iStatus = RegSetValueExString(hKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, sDisplayName, _
        Len(sDisplayName))
      iStatus = RegCloseKey(hKey)
    Else
      iStatus = RegCreateKeyEx(hLRegKey, sRoot, 0&, vbNullString, _
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, 0&, hNewKey, lRetVal)
      iStatus = RegSetValueExString(hNewKey, "", 0&, REG_SZ, _
        sDisplayName, Len(sDisplayName))
      iStatus = RegCloseKey(hNewKey)
    End If
    UpdateMenus
  End If
End Function
Private Sub UpdateMenus()
  ' Refresh the menu choices with the updated client
  Dim iRetVal As Integer
  iRetVal = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, _
    "SOFTWARE\Clients\mail")
  iRetVal = SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, _
    "SOFTWARE\Clients\StartMenuInternet")
End Sub
```

From [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/299853)